# CMD commands work in promt but not in .bat/.cmd file

Tags: batch-file, winscp

I've got the following problem. I can't get the following code to work automatic trough a .BAT file or with A script:

```
"C:\Program Files\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" 
/log="C:\Users\PC0102\Desktop\cz2\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul /loglevel=2* ^ 
/command ^ 
option batch continue 
option confirm on  
open ftps://PRC:*@datatransfer.cz.nl     
CD Incassopartner2CZ 
CD Input 
put C:\Users\PC0102\Desktop\cz2\Bestanden\ /prc/Incassopartner2CZ/Input 
exit
```

When I put this code in my cmd it's working perfect. But at the moment when I try to make a .bat file from it it only starts up winscp and does nothing else. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please learn how to [format code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) properly...

Comment: No worries, welcome to Stackoverflow. Are you able to echo something after starting the winscp.com? Does the script work without the first line?

Comment: When I copy paste my code into cmd it works perfectly. But when I put it in a .bat file the result is that the code stops dfor some reason after starting up winscp

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
start "C:\Program Files\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" 
/log="C:\Users\PC0102\Desktop\cz2\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul /loglevel=2* ^ 
/command ^ 
option batch continue 
option confirm on  
open ftps://PRC:*@datatransfer.cz.nl     
CD Incassopartner2CZ 
CD Input 
put C:\Users\PC0102\Desktop\cz2\Bestanden\ /prc/Incassopartner2CZ/Input 
exit
```

I believe the problem is that the script is waiting for the winscp to exit before running anything else. Adding the `start` command will execute next lines as soon as winscp is started, which might be what you want.

You might be using it wrong. WinSCP has a scripting mode, which is what you probably want to use. Check it out here: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting. This way, you might want to put this in a separate file, let's say **upload.txt**

```
/log="C:\Users\PC0102\Desktop\cz2\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul /loglevel=2* ^ 
/command ^ 
option batch continue 
option confirm on  
open ftps://PRC:*@datatransfer.cz.nl     
CD Incassopartner2CZ 
CD Input 
put C:\Users\PC0102\Desktop\cz2\Bestanden\ /prc/Incassopartner2CZ/Input 
exit
```

and then run it with:

```
winscp.com /script="upload.txt"
```

Comment: I want to to connect a sftp server and send files from my local pc to the server. Thats it.

Comment: I've already taken a look at it. But I'm really a beginning programmer. I tried to set it up with a script now. But now I've got a question.

C:\Users\PC0102\Desktop\cz2\WinSCP\winscp.com /script="upload.txt"
But when I start it it doesn't work. I think it's noy startign up winscp and after that it tries to start the log but it doesn't reconize the command.
http://i66.tinypic.com/x0psfa.png

Comment: Try creating this file first `C:\Users\PC0102\Desktop\cz2\WinSCP.log`

Comment: From the .bat file ? Because that's not working atm. I can give you a log when I copy paste in into cmd.

Comment: Just create it manually to see if the problem is that the log file does not exist. Maybe also get rid of the logging lines in the script and see if it works without them

Comment: open C:\Program Files\WinSCP\winscp.com /script="upload.txt"
C:\Program Files\WinSCP\winscp.com /script="upload.txt"

I've tried both of them at the first one it opens cmd and cant see that happens there.
Second one it says unknown command

Comment: why don't you cd into the winscp folder. That way you make sure the path isn't the problem.

Comment: Cool. Just put the upload.txt in the same folder and run `winscp.com /script="upload.txt"`

Comment: It says he can't find the file. I got the script.bat and the upload.txt in the same folder.

Comment: Maybe without the double quotes. Can you run `dir` in the folder and confirm you can see upload.txt in the list of files?

Comment: When i run a dir in C:\Users\PC0102\Desktop\cz2\BAT2 i can find the upload.txt file and the script.bat file